# jQuery append only happens once

Tags: jquery, append

My intention is for a new `<input>` fields to be created every time there is only one blank one left - so when the top one loses focus. This happens, but only once (so only three `<input>` fields can ever be made.

My working example is at http://sas98.user.srcf.net/guestlist/ under number 4.

The code is:

```
<div id="names">
<p><input class="input" type="text" name="name1" /></p>
<p><input class="input" type="text" name="name2" /></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var name = $("<p><input class='input' type='text' /></p>");
    $('.input').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val().length>0) {
            $('#names').append(name.clone());
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT:

```
            $('#names').append(name);
```

Changed to

```
        $('#names').append(name.clone());
```

Makes it work a couple more times before getting stuck. It seems temperamental - I can't see a pattern to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the event handler is not updated.
for Jquery < 1.7 use $.live() to bind blur,
on newer versions use $.on()

Comment: where would I add $.on() here?

Answer (score 1):

This works like you want I think: http://jsfiddle.net/YFJA6/

```
$('#names').on({
blur: function() {
    if($(this).val().length>0) {
        $('#names').append('<p><input class="input" type="text" /></p>');
    }
}
}, 'input');
```

Comment: Yea, thats another logic issue - could loop through all inputs - checking val() and make sure you don't have any blank ones - to avoid excessive blank inputs added. I just left the logic they started with though.

Comment: its not perfect since you can add input to the first two fields and switch between them and it keeps adding new fields. see http://jsfiddle.net/YFJA6/1/ for fix

Answer (score 0):

This is because you add the .blur() handler only once (before the new inputs are created), so the newest input needs to be assigned a handler for the blur event as well.

For interest sake, try:

```
<div id="names">
<p><input class="input" type="text" name="name1" /></p>
<p><input class="input" type="text" name="name2" /></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.input').blur(addBlur());
});
function addBlur() {
        var name = $("<p><input class='input' type='text' /></p>");
        if($(this).val().length>0) {
            var newBox = name.clone();
            newBox.blur(addBlur());
            $('#names').append(name.clone());
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I put the 'var name=...' in the wrong function. try again please

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

`$('#selector').append(htmlcontent.clone(true));`